# need help in understanding CCMoveTo?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have downloaded the sample demo and trying to understand it.but Stuck on following code

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self  selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

How `CCMoveTo` moves object from one location to another as this object moves from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `CCMoveTo` moves object from one location to another as this object moves from left to right.

not like left to right?

If the object(sprites) anywhere and you are willing to moveto some position from current position

example

current sprite position

(100,100)

then if you use `CCMoveTo` with (200,200) then it will move to (200,200)

then if you use `CCMoveBy` with (200,200) then it will move to

```
currentposition+neededposition
```

so (100+200,100,200) which implies (300,300);